# intensity scaling: precise definition?

Tags: image-processing

I am a little confused about definition of intensity scaling. It is something like histogram equalization or a method in which we just multiply all intensities by a scalar. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intensity scaling can be just as you say: multiplying all intensities by a scalar value. This will obviously change the histogram, but will do nothing like histogram equalization (it will just scale the x-axis of the histogram, barring some binning effects).

More generally, intensity scaling can change the range of intensities so that instead of going from $\tt x_{min}$ to $\tt x_{max}$ the pixel values range from $\tt x_{new\ min}$ to $\tt x_{new\ max}$ that might be better for display purposes (e.g. $\tt x_{new\ min} = 0$ to $\tt x_{new\ max} = 255$ or $\tt x_{new\ min} = 0$ to $\tt x_{new\ max} = 65535$).

[See Gozales, Woods, and Eddis for example.](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/dipum2e_downloads/dipum2e_sample_book_material_downloads/DIPUM2E_Chapter03_Pgs_80-114_abd_128-133.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but it is similar to histogram equalization. I think intensity scaling should be different than stretching intensities to some ranges such as [0,255]. to be more precise, if we have intensity is range of [10,64], by scaling by a factor of 3, it becomes [30,192]. is it true?

Comment: Well, it's a simpler version of histogram equalization. Intensity scaling just does a linear (or affine) modification of the pixel values.  Histogram equalization (in general) will apply a possibly nonlinear map from the input pixel values to the output pixel values (so that the histogram is equalized).  Intensity scaling does not guarantee anything about the histogram.

Comment: Yes, that can be a simple, linear, version of intensity scaling.  [10,64] ==> [30,192].

Comment: Peter as u said (10,64) and letter we scale it by 3 we got (30,192), what happens if we have (10,100) and scale it by 3 ,it will exceed the limit of 255.